# ffmpeg drawtext - only draw within clipping rectangle

Tags: filter, ffmpeg, drawtext

The ffmpeg documentation on filters doesn't have anything on a clipping rectangle for drawtext. I'm hoping there might be a setting I can put before a video filter to set a clip rect, an undocumented feature or a clever workaround so that you can draw the text only within a certain bounding box on the output video.

I'm trying to overlay movie titles over a ticking clock video. These might be long and I don't want them to spill over onto part of the clock. I know how to overlay text already. I am currently working around this by using a shorter version of the title.

Is this something that requires filter graphs or intermediate video files or can it be done with a simple video filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

## Method 1: subtitles filter

Assuming you want simple clipping, and not bounded word wrapping, you can use ASS subtitles. See [Visual Typesetting - Aegisub](http://docs.aegisub.org/manual/Visual_Typesetting#Rectangular_clip).

Once you make your subtitles file the `ffmpeg` command is simple:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "subtitles=subs.ass" output
```

If you want to avoid using Aegisub you can manually make simple SRT style subs and then use the `force_style` option to set the clipping co-ordinates. See the [subtitles filter documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles-1).

## Method 2: crop

Another method would be to use crop, drawtext, and overlay filters. You can adapt the example in [Blur specific area (without a mask)](https://superuser.com/a/901705/110524).

Comment: Subtitles don't exactly do everything I need (I also want to do marquee text) and require generating an intermediate file, so I guess I'm stuck with filter graphs (i.e. Method 2). Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to have rounded edges using the subtitles filter?